# Updating a single line in the Windows console

Tags: c, printf

I have the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st1, st2, diff;

    GetSystemTime(&st1);


    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(1);
        GetSystemTime(&st2);
        diff.wSecond = st2.wSecond - st1.wSecond;
        if (st2.wMilliseconds > st1.wMilliseconds) { diff.wMilliseconds = st2.wMilliseconds - st1.wMilliseconds; }
        else { diff.wMilliseconds = 1000 + st2.wMilliseconds - st1.wMilliseconds; diff.wSecond--; }

        printf("%d:%d\n", diff.wSecond, diff.wMilliseconds);
    }

}
```

The problem is when I execute this code in a windows command prompt it creates a new line every loop turn... what is the easiest way to create just one line of display that gets updated with the current timer in `diff` variable ?

Comment: Instead of printing a *newline* have you thought about just printing a carriage-return?

Comment: `\r` instead of `\n` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
printf("%d:%d\n", diff.wSecond, diff.wMilliseconds);
```

To this:

```
printf("%d:%d\r", diff.wSecond, diff.wMilliseconds);
```

---

Note that you might have some "left-overs" at the end of the line to deal with.

You can solve it by adding a sufficient amount of white-space characters before the `\r`.

Comment: edit : oh wait how am i supposed to deal with the leftovers ?

Comment: You can also google `printf ANSI escape codes` and find several additional options.

Comment: ok sometimes it's a bit buggy it prints a lot of numbers at the left, I think it's due to a diff.wSecond glitch but I'm not sure... anyway it works most of time very well so thank you for your help !